# IBM Mobile First Application URL Configuration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

This question is in reference to the [Documentation](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/02_01_Creating_your_first_Hybrid_Worklight_application.pdf). Slide 37 asks the following:
The correct place to specify the URL that the application uses is:

- authenticationConfig.xml.
- worklight.properties.
- application-descriptor.xml.
- This URL is set separately per platform in a dedicated settings file.

**The answer is:application-descriptor** as mentioned in the answer key. I have found this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679271/ibm-worklight-application-descriptor-xml-configuration-for-external-worklight-se) that is contradictory. Also I have looked up the applicaiton descriptor elements for 6.2 and there is no where to configure the application url here: [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_the_application_descriptor.html)

Can someone help clarify where the application url can be configured? I apologize if I have misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That quiz is outdated and should be ignored.
There is no server URL configuration in application-descriptor.xml.

That URL is being inserted to the application's worklight.plist (iOS) or wlclient.properties (Android/Windows) during build-time.

By default this will use the development server's host, port and context.
You can have this changed to a remote server in Run As -> Build Setting and Remote Target.

Comment: What about the worklight.properties under the serve/conf? That can also be used to configure the URL?

Comment: No, it cannot be used for that.